# Can I transparently forward a SQL Server Connection?

Tags: sql-server

So, I have a SQL Server connection string that points at a local database:

> Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True

I cannot change this connection string, but I would love for the SQL server to live elsewhere.

Is there some way - either with SQL Server or with something in the Operating System to make this possible? I know that the Integrated Security (aka. Windows Authentication) part will make this really hard, but I figure it's worth asking in case there is a way.

Comment: This particular connection string is tough, because "." is a built-in alias for the local machine, and that will use the shared memory protocol by default (completely bypassing the network stack). I don't think this can be redirected, short of patching the code that reads the connection string at runtime (which is a bit more realistic for .NET than for unmanaged code, but still not easy). For actual server names, you can define [aliases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms190445) through the SQL Server configuration manager, but I don't think "." can be aliased (I haven't tested it, though).

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thank you! This actually works - I can alias `.` to the other server. If you add it as an answer, I can accept it for the well deserved rep.

Comment: Well, I learned something new today, even if what I learned is a little frightening...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the client software uses the native SQL client (and almost everything does) you can alias any server name using the [SQL Server Configuration Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/create-or-delete-a-server-alias-for-use-by-a-client). In the Configuration Manager snap-in, expand the "SQL Native Client [version] Configuration" item, right-click "Aliases" and choose "New Alias..." There are two such items, for 32-bit and 64-bit, don't forget to add the alias to both places.

Use this power sparingly. *Any* server name includes special names like `.` and `(LocalDB)\MyInstance`, which normally refer only to the local machine and don't even use TCP/IP. Aliasing these can be very confusing to a casual reader. The alias is not case-sensitive, but it must otherwise match exactly, so adding blanks or using things like `localhost` instead of `.` will defeat it.

Comment: Just to add in case the version of the tools/clients/etc. matters: I do have SQL Server 2016 SP1 installed on this machine here, just no running instance (double checked that the SQL Server is indeed shut down and that I'm really hitting the target)